# How many feats/skills/powers can a player retrain on gaining a level?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-advancement, character-levels, retraining

> Every time your character gains a level, you can retrain. To do so, change one of the following: a feat, a power, or a trained skill. You can make only one change per level.

I believe that means **one change when gaining a level** but it could be interpreted as **one change per level when gaining a new level** (eg. when gaining 5th level you can make 4 changes, one on each level had).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One**

Your first interpretation is correct, it's one change each time you gain a level.